# Editing user profile: How to avoid user from entering duplicate values?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm a newbie in PHP. I wanted the display warning messages user to avoid entering duplicate values such as username, email and telephone number.

For example, user wants to change their username. When the user submit the form after editing their username, a warning message is display saying that username has already been taken or already exists.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
include("../config.php");
include("../errors.php");
include("../success.php");
$errors = array(); 
$successes = array();
if ($_SESSION["uName"]){
    if ($_SESSION["uType"] != "admin") {
        header("location:../user/dashboard_user.php");  
    } else if ($_SESSION["uType"] == "admin"){      
        if(isset($_POST["update"])) {

            $fname = $_POST["fname"];
            $telno = $_POST["telno"];
            $uname = $_POST["username"];
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];

            $password = md5($password);
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET fullname = '$fname', telno = '$telno', username = '$uname', email = '$email', password = '$password' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['uId']."'";
            if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
                array_push($successes, "Update Success!");
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
            }       

        } 
?>
```

What is the correct way to use the SELECT statement in the code to get the expected results?

Comment: Why not just create a unique index on the database, attempt to insert and then handle exception?

Comment: This code is highly vulnerable in terms of SQL injection. Additionally, where should such a message come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really handle the issue in the database:

```
create unique index idx_username on users(username);
```

Then in your code do what you do and then simply:

```
define('MYSQL_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION', 1062);

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    array_push($successes, "Update Success!");
} elsif (mysql_errno() == MYSQL_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION )  {
    echo "Error: username $username is already taken";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}
```

This code is very crude of course, but it gives you the idea. If your code inside the class, then use `const` instead of `define`.

Also, your code is very much liable to SQL injection. Use parametrised query instead of using variable inside the sql string.

Comment: In addition to this, I would recommend adding a validation on both server-side and client-side to check for duplicate values before DB operations.